# In JavaScript, why is (-1).toString and (-1 >>> 0).toString identical, yet they give different results?

Tags: javascript, oop, types, interface

The background information is: in JavaScript, there is no different between float and int.  There is only Number and it is IEEE 754 standard.  So there shouldn't be any "float" vs "int" in JavaScript. Even when the number is treated as a 32-bit integer when you do bitwise operations, the result should be Number.  In order words, there should not be a type which is "integer".

### But at least on Google Chrome and on Node.js:

#### Comparing 2 functions (function as an object):

```
(-1).toString === (-1 >>> 0).toString      // => true
```

#### So they are the same, identical function object.  In fact, the "wrapped objects" are of the same type:

```
(-1).__proto__ === (-1 >>> 0).__proto__    // => true
```

#### But when you use

```
(-1).toString(2)         // => "-1"
```

#### and

```
(-1 >>> 0).toString(2)   // => "11111111111111111111111111111111"
```

It seems like the object wrapper (the wrapper that make the primitive type 1 to become an object), will create the two objects as having the same object type (as shown by the `__proto__`), but somehow, it thinks of itself not as the same type, one as a float, and one as 32-bit integer.  Why is that?

According to the usual general principles of OOP Interface, if two objects are of the same type (of the identical type, as shown by `__proto__` being identical), shouldn't they give the same, identical result when responding to the same "message", which is `toString(2)`?

Comment: JavaScript uses a single `Number` type to represent both ints and floats. However, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_shift_operators): *shift operators convert their operands to 32-bit integers in big-endian order*, and, when applying zero-fill right shift, *the sign bit becomes 0, so the result is always non-negative.*

Answer (score 1):

**Both `-1`, `-1>>>0` are of type 'number'**

You can check it from `typeof -1` and `typeof -1>>>0` respectively.

So, both of their methods `.toString` are literally `Number.prototype.toString`, identically.
Which means all following refers to the same `Number.prototype.toString`.

```
(1).toString // Number.prototype.toString
(2).toString // Number.prototype.toString
(1.55555).toString // Number.prototype.toString
(Infinity).toString // Number.prototype.toString (Yes, typeof Infinity is Number)
(NaN).toString // Number.prototype.toString (typeof NaN is Number)
(1>>0).toString // Also Number.prototype.toString
```

That's why comparison results of their method `.toString` yields true. They are all `Number.prototype.toString`.

**It derives the same Number.prototype.toString doesn't mean it always yield the same output**.

The method takes the *different input value* will definitely return you *different resultant value*.

To illustrate the effect. Calling this.

```
(-1).toString(2);
```

Is identical to:

```
Number.prototype.toString.apply(-1,[2]); // Yields -1
```

Also, calling this:

```
(-1>>>0).toString(2);
```

Is identical to:

```
Number.prototype.toString.apply(-1>>>0,[2]); // Yields 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Now you noticed how they behave.

Comment: please see my background info in the updated question: there should not be a type Integer. There should only be Number. So why would all of a sudden, there seems like there is a type Integer object?

Comment: Why do you expect bitwise shift of an integer (Mathematical integer) to result output other than integer? Those in JavaScript are 32-bit number.  The results are still 32-bit number. The unsign bitwise shift proved that precisely well. It resulted a 32-bit number (you can even double check the type).

Answer (score 0):

This is become you are mixing up things a bit...

Why is this `true`?

```
(-1).toString === (-1 >>> 0).toString      // => true
```

Because both are `Number` and `Number.toString === Number.toString`.

I suppose that what you meant to do was:

```
(-1).toString() === (-1 >>> 0).toString()      // => false!!!
```

Notice the extra parenthesis?

In terms of number handling, as Frédéric Hamidi pointed out, the shift operations (and the bitwise operations) convert the Number to a 32 bit integer, do the math, and then convert that back to a Number. You could write the following in a typed language such as a C++ to make it clear:

```
double d = -1;
uint32_t u = static_cast<uint32_t>(d)
u >>= 1
d = static_cast<double>(u)
```

The `static_cast<>()` are not required, the language would automatically do those for you, but I put them there for clarity.

Important point, the `>>>` operator assumes that the input integer is unsigned (hence the `uint32_t`) You could think that a signed integer should be used as an intermediate, like this:

```
double d = -1;
int32_t i = static_cast<int32_t>(d)
uint32_t u = static_cast<uint32_t>(i);
u >>= 1
i = static_cast<int32_t>(u)
d = static_cast<double>(i)
```

However, this is not the case. JavaScript really converts the unsigned integers back to a `Number` (`double`). If you look at the output of `(-1 >>> 0).toString()`, you will notice that it is not `-1` anymore, instead it is `4294967295`. The largest unsigned number that can fit in 32 bits (`1 << 32 - 1`.)

Now, I suppose you understand the unsigned shift *problem* which means that the sign bit is *lost*. On 8 bits it would look like this with a 1 bit shift:

```
1111 1111 >>  1 = 1111 1111
1111 1111 >>> 1 = 0111 1111   (bit 7 becomes zero)
```

In your case, though, you used a 0 bit shift, so the value doesn't get shifted at all:

```
1111 1111 >>  0 = 1111 1111          signed, so it is -1
1111 1111 >>> 0 = 1111 1111          unsigned, so it is 255
```

but in the second case the integer becomes unsigned. Since there is enough room in the `double` mantissa to save the `uint32_t` as is, you do not lose the precision (an interesting JavaScript trick! in C++ you would certainly expect to *get the sign back* when you save the `uint32_t` in an `int32_t`... if you think like a C/C++ programmer.)

---

*P.S. your second test of the `__proto__` has the same issue. You are comparing references, not the content. In JavaScript, you have this concept of deep compare of arrays and objects ([and it can become hairy](http://moutjs.com/docs/latest/object.html#deepMatches)). `__proto__` is an object and you just compared the references. That being said, since both are `Number`s, a deep compare would also return true.*